# Backward Compatibility with JQuery 1 & 2

Tags: jquery

I provide internal serving of JQuery 1-2-3 (instead remote) in one of my extensions (but I don't use JQuery myself).

Is code written for JQuery 1 or JQuery 2 compatible with JQuery 3?

If that is the case, then I would replace all with JQuery 3.

Comment: They are mostly compatible, but some methods have been changed/removed in newer versions. Without knowing specifically what your issues are, or what methods you require compatibility with, we can't help you. The general practice here is to try it and check for errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As mentioned, extension does not use JQuery. Extension provides alternative to remote JQuery by replacing remote JQuery with local one. I want to know if JQuery 1 & 2 & 3 are replaced with JQuery 3 for the users, would there be any problems. LocalCDN & Decentraleyes extensions are examples of remote with local replacement.

Comment: `if JQuery 1 & 2 & 3 are replaced with JQuery 3 for the users, would there be any problems` Then the answer to that question is yes. There are breaking changes between versions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you. That is exactly what I was after, whether there are breaking changes or not.